# com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client does not exist

Tags: java

I'm trying to catch ClientTransportException and my program fails on compilation stage with the following exception

```
[ERROR]\workspace\rates\java\service\bundle1\src\main\java\com\connector\ws\TestClass1.java:[72,70] package com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client does not exist
```

As I know this package is from rt.jar and exist in jre

If I add @SuppressWarnings("restriction") it compiles from Eclipse Maven Plugin, but not from IntelliJ Idea(via maven) or command line neither.

When I remove @SuppressWarnings Eclipse show the following warning

```
Access restriction: The type ClientTransportException is not accessible due to restriction on required library C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar
```

I've found similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269319/package-com-sun-xml-internal-bind-v2-model-annotation-does-not-exist) but it's answer isn't clear enough for me cause I can this class in rt.jar and my IntelliJ Idea can see it either.

Can someone explain such behavior and possible solution for it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar , maybe it will help.

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading it right now, but I see only one implementation of ClientTransportException in my project.

Comment: [Why Developers Should Not Write Programs That Call 'sun' Packages](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html)

Comment: Thanks, @Jesper, I have already read this article in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269319/package-com-sun-xml-internal-bind-v2-model-annotation-does-not-exist) but it tells that I **shouldn't use it** but still I can. Unfortunately I need to catch this exception it caused by legacy of our progect

Comment: Can't you catch `javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException` instead?

Answer (score 23):

According to this [FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html) it's a bad practice to directly call 'sun' packages. When I ran into the same problem it was fixed by catching `javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException` instead (as sugested by artbristol).

Answer (score 17):

You can get rid of this error using :

```
javac -XDignore.symbol.file=true
```

That's the argument to pass to javac to use rt.jar instead of ct.sym ([ct.sym](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/247) is used by default and required for compiling to a target older version)

`ct.sym`does not contains all classes from rt.jar. Because using `sun.*` classes should not be used the class stub for them might not be present in in `ct.sym` making the compilation fails.

Removing calls to `sun.*` should remove this issue. (It's a bad practice to use sun packages)

### References :

https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/ctsym-steals-the-asm-class

> The truth of the matter is that there's something called "ct.sym" in the JDK. When javac is compiling code, it doesn't link against rt.jar. Instead, it uses a special symbol file lib/ct.sym with class stubs. Internal JDK classes are not put in that symbol file, since those are internal classes. You shouldn't want to use them, at all.

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6778491

> This is not a compiler issue. javac is behaving correctly, according to the information provided in ct.sym.
>   The issue belongs with those who decide what should be available with (and what should be hidden by) ct.sym
>   I cannot as yet determine the correct category for this bug.
>   This is intentional. Perhaps the package name "com.sun.xml.internal...." might be seen as a hint.
>   Users should not write code that depends on internal JDK implementation classes. Such classes are internal implementation details of the JDK and subject to change without notice.

http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/247

> For JDK N and --release M, M < N, signature data of the documented APIs of release M of the platform is needed. This data is stored in the $JDK_ROOT/lib/ct.sym file, which is similar, but not the same, as the file of the same name in JDK 8. The ct.sym file is a ZIP file containing stripped-down class files corresponding to class files from the target platform versions.
>   For JDK N and --release N,the JDK's own image is used as the source of the class files to compile against. The list of observable modules is limited, however, to the documented modules and the jdk.unsupported module.

---

***NOTE***

In this case, it would be better to not use the `ClientTransportException` class and replaced it by `javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException`, as suggested by **artbristol**.

Comment: The link is dead ...  :-/

Comment: @Thomas Yes, unfortunately I remember the article was quite long so I didn't quote it in the answer. Currently I can't find a new website where Andrew Haley reposted it...

Comment: Article no longer exists

Comment: @sorin7486 I've removed this old link and tried to add some understandable explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Jre System library restricts some packages access to compiler, while they are accessible to JDK. In that case there will be no error in code but when compiling it will show errors like class not found or package not found.

In that case there are two practices.
**1)** Add **rt.jar** of **jre system library** to your build path for compiling and building.
2) Add **jaxws-rt.jar** in your build path.

Second option is a good option as it will avoid adding duplicate libraries to your build path.

Comment: How to do that? could you explain this? I got a similar error here is : "package com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer does not exist" only "clien" and "developer". Could you explain your solution and how to I do that?

Comment: Go to properties of your project, where you add system libraries. you would have an option to add jre system library. add it to your build path. error should be resolved.

Answer (score 4):

import this dependency in pom.xml

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>
   </dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

The solution is quite simple: when you copy the ready-made code or write the code first and then load the dependencies, there is a dependency conflicts. `com.sun.xml.*` package is already part of JDK8, but Maven does not see it when compiling. So make sure that you use the package from mvn:repo:/...rt.jar not jdk* / .../rt.jar.[image]

Answer (score 3):

Even in 2015, I've found many projects that use this bad practice of importing `com.sun.*` packages.

If you (like me) can't change the classes importing those packages, adding `rt.jar` to your classpath should do the trick.

Note that the said `rt.jar` is usually found under `<jdk_home>/jre/lib` folder.

Answer (score 2):

Even I was facing same issue in my maven project. I had imported 
`import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ResponseContext;` in one of class file but this was not in use. 
I just commented the line in my class file and the error stopped and i could successful run my maven project.

Comment: Ahah, quite the same for me... In my case I mistakenly added `import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.AssertionValidationProcessor` with the auto completion but I wanted `org.junit.Assert`...

Answer (score 2):

For maven build adding the following plugin will resolve the issue.

Basically adding the compiler arguments to refer correct path of tools.jar

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <compilerArguments>
                <bootclasspath>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar${path.separator}${java.home}/lib/jce.jar${path.separator}${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</bootclasspath>
            </compilerArguments>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `com.sun.*` packages.
We could solve the problem by using our own class instead:

```
/**
 * Copy of com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.BindingProviderProperties since we're
 * not allowed to use com.sun.* packages..     
 */
public final class BindingProviderProperties {
    public static final java.lang.String CONNECT_TIMEOUT = "com.sun.xml.internal.ws.connect.timeout";
    public static final java.lang.String REQUEST_TIMEOUT = "com.sun.xml.internal.ws.request.timeout";
}
```

Comment: How will this help if those properties are not even used internally? What's the point of setting them?

Comment: You says that we should not use `com.sun.xml`. But you use it as package name, so you use it.