# import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException, can't read this import

Tags: java, import, jaxb

I can't resolve this problem, i try to do **import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException** but i can't import it.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 404: Not Found

at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.checkStatusCode(HttpTransportPipe.java:296)

at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.createResponsePacket(HttpTransportPipe.java:245)

at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.j
ava:203)

at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:122)

at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:95)

at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:626)

at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:585)

at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:570)

at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:467)   

at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:308)

at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:146)

at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:98)

at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)

at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:129)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't try to import the "internal" package. It's not available by design.

See this similar question for more details, and a way to override the missing import temporarily for testing, or if you have special requirements:
[com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614852/com-sun-xml-internal-ws-client-does-not-exist)

Really though, you'll want to use the publicly available parts of the API, not the internal.

Answer (score 1):

You should check WSDL url is a valid or not It means, in Web service client class. see above code.

```
static {
    URL url = null;
    WebServiceException e = null;
    try {
        url = new 
        URL("http://localhost:8084/SoapServer_test_4/CustomerService?wsdl");
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        e = new WebServiceException(ex);
    }
    CUSTOMERSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    CUSTOMERSERVICE_EXCEPTION = e;
}
```

in above code, check the WSDL url is a valid or not, or check WSDL is already hosted in that url. if your wsdl file is in your local pc, check it run like below image [you can see the wsdl url in your browser like this when you test the webservice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aK965.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use **jaxws-rt.jar** for this purpose.
rt.jar in jre system library will restrict compiler to access some of its packages.