# Problem with the maven pom.xml at the time of building

Tags: java, maven, jar

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/nflores/Desktop/AutoAtencionn/unicard-autoatencion-robots/unicard-autoatencion-robots/seguros-alta/src/main/java/cl/unicard/autoatencion/robots/segurosalta/utils/Wso2Se
rvices.java:[10,40] package com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/nflores/Desktop/AutoAtencionn/unicard-autoatencion-robots/unicard-autoatencion-robots/seguros-alta/src/main/java/cl/unicard/autoatencion/robots/segurosalta/utils/Wso2Se
rvices.java:[145,9] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ContentType
  location: class cl.unicard.autoatencion.robots.segurosalta.utils.Wso2Services
[INFO] 2 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.617 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-01-28T22:57:56-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project seguros-alta: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/nflores/Desktop/AutoAtencionn/unicard-autoatencion-robots/unicard-autoatencion-robots/seguros-alta/src/main/java/cl/unicard/autoatencion/robots/segurosalta/utils/Wso2Se
rvices.java:[10,40] package com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/nflores/Desktop/AutoAtencionn/unicard-autoatencion-robots/unicard-autoatencion-robots/seguros-alta/src/main/java/cl/unicard/autoatencion/robots/segurosalta/utils/Wso2Se
rvices.java:[145,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ContentType
[ERROR]   location: class cl.unicard.autoatencion.robots.segurosalta.utils.Wso2Services
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I developed a project in java, which I made with maven and profiles but at the time of compiling or generating the package I got this error.

Why is the error due?

Comment: You are trying to import `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe`, but none of your dependencies have that package.

Answer (score 1):

It is more correct to say that the problem is with program compilation, there is nothing to do with pom.xml (maybe later to solve this problem you will need to add some external dependencies, but currently the problem is not with the pom.xml)

You have 2 errors during compilation of your Wso2Services.java file. The first error message says, that compiler failed to find package with name "com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe", and the second one says that compiler does not find a declaration of the ContentType class.

It looks like you are trying to import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.ContentType. But by design Java does not allow to import internal classes. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632398/import-com-sun-xml-internal-ws-client-clienttransportexception-cant-read-this/44843920#44843920)